# How save multiple values JSONStore

Tags: save, ibm-mobilefirst, savechanges, jsonstore, multivalue

I need to replace multiple value in JSONStore of IBM Worklight. 
In this way is saved only first value. Why?

```
 .then(function() {                             
   for (var index = 0; index < elencoSpese.length; index++) {                                          
       var spesa = elencoSpese[index];                              
       var spesaReplace = {_id: spesa.id, json: spesa};                                 
       spesa.id_nota_spesa = idNotaSpesa;                               
       spesa.checked = true;                            
       WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME_SPESE).replace(spesaReplace);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build an array of JSONStore documents and pass it to the `replace`API. For example:

```
.then(function() {

    var replacementsArray = [];

    for (var index = 0; index < elencoSpese.length; index++) {
        var spesa = elencoSpese[index];
        var spesaReplace = {_id: spesa.id, json: spesa};
        spesa.id_nota_spesa = idNotaSpesa;
        spesa.checked = true;
        replacementsArray.push(spesaReplace);
    }

    return WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME_SPESE).replace(replacementsArray);

})
.then(function (numOfDocsReplaced) {
    // numOfDocsReplaced should equal elencoSpese.length
})
```

I assume this happens in the JavaScript implementation of the JSONStore API, if that's the case the answer is in the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_troubleshooting_overview.html). *The JavaScript implementation of JSONStore expects code to be called serially. Wait for an operation to finish before you call the next one.* When you call the `replace` multiple times without waiting, you're calling the API in parallel instead of serially. This should not be an issue in the production environments (i.e. Android, iOS, WP8 and W8).